# wrong symbols in oh-my-zsh Agnoster Theme

Tags: gnome-terminal, fonts

I installed oh-my-zsh and on top of that solarized as well as menlo. However, if I pick under "Profile preferences" in the terminal the menlo font, the extra characters are displayed wrong.

Does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you need to install powerline fonts.

Comment: I did do that already oO

Comment: Just to be sure, also double check that your encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: What is the update? Has this problem gone?

Comment: it has been resolved by me changing the font to inconsolata -.-

Answer (score 2):

As @egmont said in comments, you need to install fonts powerline. Execute:

```
sudo apt install fonts-powerline
```

And the problem will be solved after restart the terminal.